# Elasticsearch: Need offset of exact matching string

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer, elasticsearch-5

I have a html files and I need to find section around exact matching string, say "ANNUAL REPORT PURSUANT". I am using latest version of Elasticsearch 5.4.0. I am new to elasticsearch. For indexing I have defined analyzer as below:

```
{
    "index_name": {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "provided_name": "index_name",
                "creation_date": "1496927173220",
                "analysis": {
                    "analyzer": {
                        "contact_section_analyzer": {
                            "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
                        }
                    },
                    "tokenizer": {
                        "my_tokenizer": {
                            "pattern": "(ANNUAL REPORT PURSUANT)",
                            "type": "pattern",
                            "group": "1"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "vF3cAe-STJW-GrVxc7N8ww",
                "version": {
                    "created": "5040099"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to get offset using analyze as below:

```
POST localhost:9200/sag_sec_items6/_analyze?pretty
{
  "analyzer": "contact_section_analyzer", 
  "text": "my_html_file_contents_already_indexed"
}
```

It returns:

```
{
    "tokens": []
}
```

I checked html files they contain that text.

Using _search query with individual _ids I get whole html file back.
How can I get **offsets or the html tags** containing that text.

Answer (score 0):

I redefined my analyzer settings as below:

```
"settings": {
        "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
        "contact_section_start_analyzer": {
                "char_filter": "html_strip",
                "tokenizer": "contact_section_start_tokenizer"
        }
        },
        "tokenizer": {
        "contact_section_start_tokenizer": {
                "flags": "CASE_INSENSITIVE|DOTALL",
                "pattern": "\\b(annual\\s+report\\s+pursuant)\\b",
                "type": "pattern",
                "group": "1"
        }
        }
        }
        }
```

With this change in regex pattern and including CASE_INSENSITIVE|DOTALL flag in pattern analyzer I am able to get the offsets.